# Javascript framework suggestion for displaying dynamic data

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dashboard

To give a background of what the user interface for the application I am creating does:

I am designing a sort of dashboard for a list of people who clocked into work on a particular day. The basic design is the names of people will be on slices of a donut chart, when they clock into work on a day, their slice color will change from red to green indicating that they are in work today. The user of the dashboard will also be able to click or hover over one of the slices to have it expand and show more detailed information about the person (more text).

I have the back-end of my sample application ready to serve data to be displayed by a UI, but I am not sure how I should go about designing this. What I am asking is if there are any JavaScript frameworks that would make this easy to implemented. I already looked at a bunch of tools such as Google Charts, ,ChartJS, and D3.js, but that seems more focuses on displaying actual numerical data rather than textual which is what I am going for.

Any suggestion into frameworks or technologies would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Raphael](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) as charting library.
While [D3](https://d3js.org/) is much more powerfull, it comes with a a bit steeper learning curve. IMO using Raphael will get you quickly started.

I hope it helps